# How to show full width background color on tree node CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a tree and there is `background-color` change on hover of tree node. I want to show `background-color` on full width like in [this example](https://tina-material-tree.firebaseapp.com/simple-tree)(on click of any node it shows gray color).

But the element on which I am applying the `background-color` is not full width itself. How can I achieve this?

```css
.qwc-tree__branch {
  padding-left: 40px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.tree__root {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.tree__node {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative
}

.tree__node::before,
.tree__node::after {
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto
}

.tree__node::before {
  border-left: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px
}

.tree__node::after {
  border-top: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;
  height: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 25px
}

.tree__root>.tree__root-node::before {
  border: 0;
}

.tree__root>.tree__root-node::after {
  border: 0;
}

.tree__node-header:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.tree__node-name {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.tree__node-name--icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 3px;
  color: $primary;
}

.tree__node-action {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px
}

tree .tree__node:last-child::before {
  height: 30px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="tree__branch tree__root">
  <li class="tree__node tree__root-node">
    <div class="tree__node-header">
      <span class="tree__node-name">
    <i class="material-icons tree__node-name--icon">assignment</i> India
   
   </span>
      <i class="material-icons tree__node-action">minimize</i>
    </div>
    <ul class="tree__branch">
      <li class="tree__node">
        <div class="tree__node-header">
          <span class="tree__node-name">
      <i class="material-icons tree__node-name--icon">assignment</i> Punjab
     
     </span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="tree__node">
        <div class="tree__node-header">
          <span class="tree__node-name">
      <i class="material-icons tree__node-name--icon">assignment</i> Haryana
        
     </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its working fine on my machine. Any specific browser device its not working ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma I see the issue on my browser in the example snippet. I think OP meant that highlight is not spanning the entire row for the sub list elements ( it starts where the sublist starts)

Comment: Thanks @ChiragRavindra for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo element to simulate the background and make it overflowing:

```
.tree__node-header:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-40px; /*adjust this*/
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Full code:

```css
.qwc-tree__branch {
  padding-left: 40px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  
}

.tree__root {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
  /*added this*/
.tree__root>.tree__root-node>.tree__node-header {
  overflow:hidden;
}
 /**/
.tree__node {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative
}

.tree__node::before,
.tree__node::after {
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto
}

.tree__node::before {
  border-left: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px
}

.tree__node::after {
  border-top: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;
  height: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 25px
}

.tree__root>.tree__root-node::before {
  border: 0;
}

.tree__root>.tree__root-node::after {
  border: 0;
}

.tree__node-header:hover,
.tree__node-header:hover:after { /*Added this*/
  background-color: lightblue;
}
/*Added this*/
.tree__node-header {
  position:relative;
}

.tree__node-header:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-45px;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
/* */
.tree__node-name {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.tree__node-name--icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 3px;
  color: $primary;
}

.tree__node-action {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px
}

tree .tree__node:last-child::before {
  height: 30px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="tree__branch tree__root">
  <li class="tree__node tree__root-node">
    <div class="tree__node-header">
      <span class="tree__node-name">
    <i class="material-icons tree__node-name--icon">assignment</i> India
   
   </span>
      <i class="material-icons tree__node-action">minimize</i>
    </div>
    <ul class="tree__branch">
      <li class="tree__node">
        <div class="tree__node-header">
          <span class="tree__node-name">
      <i class="material-icons tree__node-name--icon">assignment</i> Punjab
     
     </span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="tree__node">
        <div class="tree__node-header">
          <span class="tree__node-name">
      <i class="material-icons tree__node-name--icon">assignment</i> Haryana
        
     </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks!! but for root element it got expanded too, I want the same size background width wise?

Comment: @SunilGarg check the update ;) we simply need to put the overflow:hidden in the right place

Comment: Can you please comment what changes you have made?

Comment: this works for only 2 level. is not there anyway if there are multiple levels it should behave the same?

Comment: @SunilGarg yes it can, you simply need to play with the `left` property and overflow, here I used a fixed value that you need to make bigger for the next level

Comment: and how can make variable value in left property?

Comment: @SunilGarg I would say, make it always very big and use overlfow:hidden to hide the extra overflow